# Replace string with contents of a file using sed

Tags: sed, replace

I have two different files:

#### File1

```
/home/user1/  
/home/user2/bin  
/home/user1/a/b/c
```

#### File2

```
<TEXT1>
<TEXT2>
```

I want to replace the `<TEXT1>` of *File2* with the contents of *File1* using `sed`. I tried this command, but not getting proper output:

```
cat File2|sed "s/<TEXT1>/$(cat File1|sed 's/\//\\\//g'|sed 's/$/\\n/g'|tr -d "\n")/g"
```

You can use other tools also to solve this problem.

Comment: Please paste that error message so we can locate its source. Also tell us which `sed` implementation are you using. You code works for me with GNU `sed`.

Comment: Sorry, Not getting an error. I am not getting desired output. Output is like `/home/user1/ n/home/user2/bin n/home/user1/a/b/cn <TEXT2>`. Not getting new lines.

Comment: Not sure if this would apply in your specific case, but with `diff` and `patch` tools allow to replace some lines in a file by other lines quite easily.

Comment: Btw, using random data gathered with `$()` in a sed script makes my eyes bleed. **Never** use external data in places where some characters are interpreted with special meaning.

Comment: Similar question: [Substitute pattern within a file with the content of other file](/q/49377)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace text between two markers in a file with a section of text from another file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212009/how-to-replace-text-between-two-markers-in-a-file-with-a-section-of-text-from-an)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a sed script solution (easier on the eyes than trying to get it into one line on the command line):

```
/<TEXT1>/ {
  r File1
  d
}
```

Running it:

```
$ sed -f script.sed File2
/home/user1/
/home/user2/bin
/home/user1/a/b/c
<TEXT2>
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. But I don't want to use any other script file. Are there any inline solution?

Comment: Sure: `sed '/<TEXT1>/{rFile1^Md^M}' File2`, where "^M" is you pressing return. The problem is that sed really needs the newlines within the {...} to delimit the r and the d command.

Comment: with bash, posix-style strings are a bit cleaner: `sed $'/<TEXT1>/ {r File1\n d}'`

Comment: Also with [-e](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/31092-replace-string-content-another-file.html#4) for a one liner: `sed -e '/<TEXT1>/{r File1' -e 'd}' File2`

Comment: And what if instead of replacing the entire line containing `<TEXT1>`, I just want to replace the string itself, leaving the rest of the line intact? `Text1: <TEXT1>` to `Text1: <file_contents>`.

Comment: @RobinWinslow - you could use any of the working solutions [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/172399) (you will just have to slightly adjust the code to replace the pattern instead of appending after pattern).

Answer (score 14):

Took me a long time to find this solution using var replacement. All sed solutions did not work for me, as they either delete complete lines or replace incorrectly.

```
FILE2=$(<file2)
FILE1=$(<file1)
echo "${FILE2//TEXT1/$FILE1}"
```

Replaces all occurences of TEXT1 in file2 against content of file1. All other text remains untouched.

Comment: very nice. possibly faster than `sed` too, since those "expansions" (aka replacements) are built into the shell (`bash` at least)

Comment: Thank you!
You can pip multiple files to this genius method using a `while read` method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33079920/13415228)

Answer (score 7):

I answer because the `diff`/`patch` method might be of interest in some cases.
To define a substitution of lines contained in file `blob1` by lines contained in `blob2` use:

```
diff -u blob1 blob2 > patch-file
```

For example, if `blob1` contains:

```
hello
you
```

and `blob2` contains:

```
be
welcome
here
```

the generated `patch-file` will be:

```
--- blob1   2011-09-08 16:42:24.000000000 +0200
+++ blob2   2011-09-08 16:50:48.000000000 +0200
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
-hello
-you
+be
+welcome
+here
```

Now, you can apply this patch to any other file:

```
patch somefile patch-file
```

It will replace `hello`,`you` lines by `be`,`welcome`,`here` lines in `somefile`.

Comment: this is really clever but would be better if you could automate it in a script