# sed load substitute from file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm attempting to replace a pattern in a file with the complete contents of another file using sed.

Currently I am using:

```
sed "s/PATTERN/`cat replacement.txt`/g" "openfile.txt" > "output.txt"
```

However, if the replacement file contains any characters such as `'`, `"`, or `/` I start getting errors due to input not being sanitized.

I have been trying to use [this guide](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-37) to aid me, but I am finding it quite hard to follow. If I try the suggested `r file` command, I just end up with a string.

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20324/47538) should work for you. I did not vote to close as duplicate since you had specified you have `'`, `/` and `"` characters in your file. So, I did the testing as below.

I have `file1` contents as below.

```
cat file1
ramesh' has " and /
in this file
and trying
"to replace'
the contents in 
/other file.
```

Now, `file2` is as below.

```
cat file2
This is file2
PATTERN 
After pattern contents go here.
```

As per the shared link, I created the `script.sed` as below.

```
cat script.sed
/PATTERN/ {
  r file1
  d
}
```

Now, when I run the command as `sed -f script.sed file2`, I get the output as,

```
This is file2
ramesh' has " and /
in this file
and trying
"to replace'
the contents in 
/other file.
After pattern contents go here.
```

**EDIT**: This works well with multiple patterns in the file as well.

Comment: This worked great. Thank you. What is the purpose of the delete command?

Comment: @Sam, do you mean the `d` at the end of `script.sed` file? I tried removing it and ran it and still got the same output. So, I am not sure what exactly it does.

Comment: @Ramesh: Without `d`, `PATTERN` remain in the file.

Comment: Note that it doesn't replace `PATTERN` with the content of the file, but any full line containing PATTERN with the content of the file.

Answer (score 4):

If you need an `awk` solution, you could use something like below.

```
 awk '/PATTERN/{system("cat file1");next}1' file2
```

**Testing**

```
cat file1
ramesh' has " and /
in this file
and trying
"to replace'
the contents in 
/other file.
```

Now, I have `file2` as below.

```
cat file2
This is file2
PATTERN 
After pattern contents go here.
PATTERN
```

Now, I use the above mentioned `awk` command.

**Output:**

```
This is file2
ramesh' has " and /
in this file
and trying
"to replace'
the contents in 
/other file.
After pattern contents go here.
ramesh' has " and /
in this file
and trying
"to replace'
the contents in 
/other file.
```

**References**

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/158315-replace-string-contents-txt-file-containing-multiple-lines-strings.html

Comment: I appreciate that you took the time to provide two solutions. Thank you.

Comment: @Ramesh: This `awk` won't work if line have something like `QWERTY PATTERN`. It skip the whole line instead of replace `PATTERN`.

Comment: @cuonglm is there a way to make this filename(file1 - which is providing stdout using cat) variable in this command?

Comment: @fireball.1 You can use `ARGV` variable to access arguments.

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
sed "s/PATTERN/`cat replacement.txt`/g" "openfile.txt"
```

`'` and `"` should not be a problem. Those are not special to `sed`. What should be a problem is `&`, `\`, `/` and newline. You can escape those with another `sed` command:

```
sed "s/PATTERN/$(sed 's@[/\&]@\\&@g;$!s/$/\\/' replacement.txt)/g" openfile.txt
```

Note that it removes the trailing newline characters in `replacement.txt`. If that's not want you want, you can do

```
replacement=$(sed 's@[/\&]@\\&@g;s/$/\\/' replacement.txt; echo .)
replacement=${replacement%.}
sed "s/PATTERN/$replacement/g" openfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does it work running "sed 's@[/\&]@\\&@g;$!s/$/\\/' replacement.txt" escapes the problem chars, but how are they removed when inserted to openfile.txt ?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed` you can just `e`xecute `cat` at whatever point of the script you like. Unlike `r` - which schedules for output for the end of the line cycle *(which can be very frustrating!)*, `e` works like `i` or `c` in that it immediately writes its output. Here are some examples of its use:

```
printf %s\\n 'these are some words' \
    'that will each appear' \
    'on their own line' | 
    sed 's/.*words/echo & ; cat file/e'
these are some words
these
are
some
more
words    
that
are
stored
in
a
file
that will each appear
on their own line
```

And here's how you might use this:

```
printf %s\\n 'these are some words' \
    'that will each appear' \
    'on their own line' | 
sed 's/\(.*\)\n*words/\1\n&/;//P;s//\ncat file/ep;s/.*\n//'
these are some 
these
are
some
more
words
that
are
stored
in
a
file
that will each appear
on their own line
```