# Find & replace image URLs in one file from another file

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I am trying to replace all the image source URLs in an HTML file from a list of URLs in a text file.

**File1.html**

```
<td class="MetadataRes" width="380px" colspan="2" style="border-top: 1px #336699 solid;">
  <a olv_link="/Default/Scripting/ArticleWin.asp?From=Search&amp;Key=Orange/2011/03/27/129/Ad12911.xml&amp;CollName=Orange_APA3&amp;DOCID=2485870&amp;PageLabelPrint=H2&amp;Skin=%4f%72%61%6e%67%65%43%6f%75%6e%74%79%52%65%67%69%73%74%65%72&amp;AW=%31%34%31%32%36%32%38%32%31%34%35%30%32&amp;sPublication=%4f%72%61%6e%67%65&amp;sScopeID=%44%52&amp;SECTION=%43%6c%61%73%73%69%66%69%65%64&amp;sSorting=%53%63%6f%72%65%2c%64%65%73%63&amp;sQuery=%72%65%67%69%73%74%65%72%65%64%20%6e%75%72%73%65%20%3c%4f%52%3e%20%52%4e&amp;rEntityType=&amp;sSearchInAll=%66%61%6c%73%65&amp;sDateFrom=%25%33%30%25%33%35%25%32%66%25%33%30%25%33%31%25%32%66%25%33%32%25%33%30%25%33%31%25%33%30&amp;sDateTo=%25%33%30%25%33%35%25%32%66%25%33%33%25%33%31%25%32%66%25%33%32%25%33%30%25%33%31%25%33%31&amp;dc:creator=&amp;PageLabel=&amp;dc:publisher=&amp;RefineQueryView=&amp;StartFrom=%30" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.top.sys.openArtWin(this.getAttribute('Olv_link'))">
    <img src="/Repository/GetImage.dll?baseHref=Orange/2011/03/27&amp;EntityID=Ad12911&amp;imgExtension=">
  </a>
</td>...
```

* See full file here: http://pastebin.com/XbwtZJPa

**File2.txt**

```
/getimage.dll?path=Orange/2011/03/27/129/Img/Ad1291103.gif
/getimage.dll?path=Orange/2011/03/20/133/Img/Ad1330402.gif
/getimage.dll?path=Orange/2010/08/29/137/Img/Ad1372408.gif
```

I want to replace the URL for the image in the above HTML file with the first URL listed in the URL file to get the following:

**Result.html**

```
<td class="MetadataRes" width="380px" colspan="2" style="border-top: 1px #336699 solid;">
  <a olv_link="/Default/Scripting/ArticleWin.asp?From=Search&amp;Key=Orange/2011/03/27/129/Ad12911.xml&amp;CollName=Orange_APA3&amp;DOCID=2485870&amp;PageLabelPrint=H2&amp;Skin=%4f%72%61%6e%67%65%43%6f%75%6e%74%79%52%65%67%69%73%74%65%72&amp;AW=%31%34%31%32%36%32%38%32%31%34%35%30%32&amp;sPublication=%4f%72%61%6e%67%65&amp;sScopeID=%44%52&amp;SECTION=%43%6c%61%73%73%69%66%69%65%64&amp;sSorting=%53%63%6f%72%65%2c%64%65%73%63&amp;sQuery=%72%65%67%69%73%74%65%72%65%64%20%6e%75%72%73%65%20%3c%4f%52%3e%20%52%4e&amp;rEntityType=&amp;sSearchInAll=%66%61%6c%73%65&amp;sDateFrom=%25%33%30%25%33%35%25%32%66%25%33%30%25%33%31%25%32%66%25%33%32%25%33%30%25%33%31%25%33%30&amp;sDateTo=%25%33%30%25%33%35%25%32%66%25%33%33%25%33%31%25%32%66%25%33%32%25%33%30%25%33%31%25%33%31&amp;dc:creator=&amp;PageLabel=&amp;dc:publisher=&amp;RefineQueryView=&amp;StartFrom=%30" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.top.sys.openArtWin(this.getAttribute('Olv_link'))">
    <img src="/Repository/getimage.dll?path=Orange/2011/03/27/129/Img/Ad1291103.gif">
  </a>
</td>...
```

Is there a recommended shell command to do this?  I considered the following sed command on my Mac running 10.9 but ran into errors.

```
$ gsed -e 's/.*SRC="\/Repository\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p{r File1.html' -e 'd}' File2.txt
```

Comment: I believe this regular expression finds all the URLs in File1.html

\/Repository\/([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?

Comment: You ran into _what_ errors? How is this different to your question [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/161817/22222)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `EntityID` contains a unique string to identify the correct URL from File2.txt this here does the trick not only for your example:

```
sed '\_^/getimage.dll.*gif$_{H;d}
  G;s/<img src="[^"]*EntityID=\([^&]*\)&[^"]*"\(.*\)\n\(\/getimage[^\n]*\1[^.]*.gif\).*/<img src="\3"/;s/\n.*//' File2.txt File1.html
```

Ask for the explanation if needed.