# Insert text from file inline after matching pattern in another file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I'm trying to take the contents of a file and insert it after a matching pattern in another file using sed. My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836306/add-text-between-two-patterns-in-file-using-sed-command), but I wish to insert the contents of a file inline rather than on a new line. How can I do this?

Using the example question I referenced, the first answer does exactly what I want; however, I want the insertion to happen inline:

```
sed '/First/r file1.txt' infile.txt
```

The actual data I want to insert is a JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "foo": "bar", 
        "baz": "biff",
        "data": [
            {
                "a": 1945619, 
                "b": [
                    {
                        "c": 512665, 
                        "d": "futz"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I *think* [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164551/52934) answers your question. Would you look at it and let me know?

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks for the help. I'd happy to try your solution, but after reading your solution, I'm not sure how to implement what you suggest. Can you post an example?

Comment: I'm definitely considering it - it looks simple enough - but I dunno where to start... OOps. the pattern is `First` - duh. sorry.

Comment: Wait - you want to insert the JSON newline free - like remove the newlines from the inserted file as it is inserted? I can do that with GNU `sed` but I just wanna make sure...

Comment: The actual JSON does not need to be altered, I want to insert the JSON after the pattern so that there is not a newline between the pattern and the start of the JSON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your linked question there is already good `awk` answer, just modify it a little bit by using `printf` instead of `print` to insert the content without newline:

```
awk '/First/ { printf $0; getline < "File1.txt" }1' infile.txt
```

Result:

```
Some Text here
FirstThis is text to be inserted into the File.
Second
Some Text here
```

You may want to add space or other delimeter after "First" with `printf $0 " "; ...`

---

If inserted file has many lines then:

```
awk '/First/{printf $0; while(getline line<"File1.txt"){print line};next}1' infile.txt
```

Result:

```
Some Text here
First[
    {
        "foo": "bar", 
        "baz": "biff",
        "data": [
            {
                "a": 1945619, 
                "b": [
                    {
                        "c": 512665, 
                        "d": "futz"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
Second
Some Text here
```

Comment: In my actual use case, I'm inserting a large JSON file and this awk example doesn't work. I just get a single left brace, `[` inserted after the pattern match. Normal text works fine, but not JSON?

Comment: Added an example JSON data file that does not insert correctly for me.

Comment: @turtle that maybe because `getline` reads in one line. Use a loop around `getline`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32911/70524

Comment: Ok, that worked, but the JSON is getting inserted right BEFORE the pattern now: `awk '/First/ { while(getline line<"File1.txt"){print line} }1' infile.txt`

Comment: @turtle try `awk '/First/ { print; while(getline line<"File1.txt"){print line} }' infile.txt` instead.

Comment: @turtle see the update.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice it. +1.

Comment: This doesn't seem to append after PATTERN if PATTERN is in the middle of a string, it appends at the end of line, irrespective of PATTERN position.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `perl` (get the file content and substitute `pattern` with `pattern`+`file content`):

```
perl -pe '$text=`cat insert.txt`; chomp($text); s/PAT/$&$text/' file.txt
```

add `-i` to edit in place; `g` to append after each PAT (pattern) occurrence, e.g.:

```
perl -i -pe '$text=`cat insert.txt`; chomp($text); s/PAT/$&$text/g' file.txt
```

---

Another way, using `ed`:

```
printf '%s\n' /PAT/s/PAT/\&\\ \/ - kb ". r insert.txt" j \'b j ,p q | ed -s file.txt
```

to edit in-place, replace `,p` with `w`:

```
 printf '%s\n' /PAT/s/PAT/\&\\ \/ - kb ". r insert.txt" j \'b j w q | ed -s file.txt
```

Probably no one is interested how this works but anyway, `printf` passes a list of commands to `ed`:

```
/PAT/s/PAT/&\             #   set address to first line matching PAT and
/                         #   split the line right after PAT
-                         #   set address one line before (return to the line matching PAT)
kb                        #   mark the current line
. r insert.txt            #   insert content of insert.txt after this line         
j                         #   join current line and the next
'b                        #   set  address to marked line (return to the line matching PAT)
j                         #   join current line and the next one
,p                        #   print file content
q                         #   quit editor
```

Or, without using `printf` and `|`:

```
ed -s file.txt <<< $'/PAT/s/PAT/&\\\n/\n-\nkb\n. r insert.txt\nj\n\'b\nj\nw\nq\n'
```

Comment: I once spent a solid 8 hours shoulders deep in `ex` docs - I really like the `vi` console window thing you can do. A single line or an adjustable size or...well, lots of stuff probably, that I just never got the hang of. Anyway, I really do wanna figure it out though - I was just poring over the POSIX docs. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Not many resources (that I know of, alas) covering `ed`... the POSIX docs, there's also [this page](http://softpanorama.org/Editors/Exorama/index.shtml)... I recommend using the tool for simple tasks/experimenting (at least, that's how I've learned,  reading only the docs, Kernighan's [short intro](http://wolfram.schneider.org/bsd/7thEdManVol2/edtut/edtut.pdf) and Krummins' [cheat sheet](http://www.catonmat.net/download/ed.text.editor.cheat.sheet.pdf)). With your knowledge of `sed`, you should have no problems. Unless your question is about `ex` (I don't use `ex` much, if at all)...

Comment: it is about `ex` - which, as I understand it, is just an `ed` extension? one thing that threw me when I played with it was the tmp storage - I tried loading up a big file and had to wait for it. on the other hand, what I find attractive about that is the innumerable buffers - I just wasn't good enough to split them out efficiently. thanks for the links.

Answer (score 6):

So it would be a little tricky to make this work portably in `sed` - you should be looking to `cut` and/or `paste` with some regex precursor generating their script in that context - and this is because `sed` will always insert a `\n`ewline *before* the output of a `r`ead. Still, w/ GNU `sed`:

```
sed '/First/{x;s/.*/cat file/e;H;x;s/\n//}' <<\IN 
First
Second
Third
IN
```

That works by `e`xecuting `cat` every time it encounters your `/First/` address. It does this in the `h`old space *(kind of - an alternate buffer anyway - because I e`x`change them it actually happens in pattern space which used to be `h`old space)* so as to preserve the contents of the line matching `First` and then appends `cat`'s output to your line and removes the intervening `\n`ewline.

#### OUTPUT:

```
First[
    {
        "foo": "bar", 
        "baz": "biff",
        "data": [
            {
                "a": 1945619, 
                "b": [
                    {
                        "c": 512665, 
                        "d": "futz"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
Second
Third
```

Now if you want the entire contents of the file to fit *between* two portions of a line that has to work a little differently because with the above command I just remove the trailing newline between the *end* of the matching line and the beginning of the file. Still, you can do this, too:

```
sed '/First/{s//&\n/;h
         s/.*/{ cat file; echo .; }/e;G
         s/\(.*\).\n\(.*\)\n/\2\1/
}' <<\IN
Third
Second
First Second Third
Third
Second
First Second Third
IN
```

That splits the line at the match with a `\n`ewline character, saves it in `h`old space, `e`xecutes `cat` - which replaces pattern space with its output - `G`ets the contents of the hold space appended to our new pattern space following another `\n`ewline character, and then rearranges on `\n`ewline delimiters.

I do `echo .` to preserve any trailing `\n`ewline characters in `file` - but if that is not your wish *(and isn't very relevant to your example anyway)* you can do without it and remove the first `.` before `.\n` in the following `s///`ubstitution.

Just before the rearrange pattern space looks like this:

```
^cat's output - any number of newlines.*.\nmatch on First\nrest of match$
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Third
Second
First[
    {
        "foo": "bar", 
        "baz": "biff",
        "data": [
            {
                "a": 1945619, 
                "b": [
                    {
                        "c": 512665, 
                        "d": "futz"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
] Second Third 
Third
Second
First[
    {
        "foo": "bar", 
        "baz": "biff",
        "data": [
            {
                "a": 1945619, 
                "b": [
                    {
                        "c": 512665, 
                        "d": "futz"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
] Second Third
```

Comment: That's a great answer Mike.

Comment: @don_crissti - thanks very much. The `s///e` is syntax is pretty cool - you can do anything you with it that you might do at a prompt. In fact, it makes for a pretty handy prompt processor as well. I've experimented with it and some more basic shells which don't provide much in the way of line editing and come away impressed. If you use it though, remember to take care that you remove *all* of a pattern space when you do - replacing only a portion of arbitrary data and then `e`xecuting the results can be disastrous. I know - I've been there.