# sed to replace a word from a file with the contents of another file?

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression

I have two files `file1` & `file2`.

Contents of file1:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

Contents of file2:

```
Sample1 
Sample2
Sample3
```

I would like to replace the word Text1 from `file1` with the contents of `file2`. I already tried the below commands:

```
sed -i 's/Text1/r file2/g' file1
sed -e 's/Text1/`cat file1`/' < file2
```

Neither of which worked, what am I missing?

Comment: You want to insert the whole file? Is it necessary to use `sed` or would an `awk` solution be OK, too?

Comment: Yeah the whole file.I can use `awk` or `sed`

Comment: Based on your description of what you want to do, it sounds like `cp file2 file1` should work. If this is not the case, please clarify your question.

Comment: If you want to replace just one word in your file with the content of another file, there's a similar question here: [Insert text from file inline after matching pattern in another file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/172399). `You could modify mike's second solution and have it replace the pattern with the content of another file.

Comment: jordanm: Aaah sorry the file1 contains the other text also...Updated the question.

Comment: @don_crissti - funny, I only noticed your comment at all after spending 5 minutes trying to find a link to that question because I wanted to vote to close this one. My answer does not stand alone there either - nor even tall - `awk`, `ed`, and `sed` are all well represented. All three answers not only provide workable solutions, but also describe how and why the solutions are workable.

Comment: @don_crissti @mikeserv: Ok...Finally I eneded up by adding the below lines `sed -i '/Text1/r file1' file2` `sed -i '/Text1/d' file2`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace just a `word` (not a full sting) you have to use some trick:

```
sed "s/100/$(cat -E file2 |tr -d '\n')/;s/\\$/\n/g" file1
```

or

```
sed -e s/100/$(tr \\n $ < file2)/ -e s/\\$/\\n/g file1
```

The main idea that `sed` is a *string* editor so it can't accept multiline string (that is mean *with newline symbols*) in most case. The trick is to strip the newline symbols from file to exchange, make substitution and than put them back.

Answer (score -1):

If all you want to do is replace file1 with file2's contents, then any of the following will work:

```
cat file2 > file1

cp file2 file1
```

Comment: No this is not the case.The file1 contains the other information also not only text1.Updated the question.