# How to substitute a string in file with another file?

Tags: sed, replace

I have several files that all contain a string. This string needs to be replaced by the whole content of another file (that can possibly be multi-line). How can I do this?

What I need is something like `sed -i 's/string/filename/' *` where `filename` is an actual file and not the string "filename".

Additional info: The file can contain special characters such as `/` or `\` or `|` or `[` or `]`.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of: [Insert text from file inline after matching pattern in another file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/172399)

Comment: Is the replacement text a single line or multiple lines?

Comment: @glennjackman It can be. Would the solution be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash works well for this:

```
$ cat replace
foo/bar\baz
the second line

$ cat file
the replacement string goes >>here<<

$ repl=$(<replace)

$ str="here"

$ while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "${line//$str/$repl}"
done < file
```

```
the replacement string goes >>foo/bar\baz
the second line<<
```

Awk would work, except that it will interpret backslash escapes (the `\b` in my example)

```
$ awk -v string="here" -v replacement="$(<replace)" '
    {gsub(string, replacement); print}
' file
the replacement string goes >>foo/baaz
the second line<<
```

Comment: For my intented use case the bash version works best and is the most flexible. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need the underused sed command **r** which reads a file:

```
sed -i '/string/{r filename
                 d}'
```

I assume you want to replace the whole line, else replace d by something suitable.

Comment: _else_ there is nothing suitable as `r` _always inserts a newline before the ouput of a read_

Comment: correct: `r` ignores the pattern space, but you can remove the `d` and do (eg) `s/string/something else/`. This changed line will appear before the file contents.

Comment: The point was that you _cannot_ insert the content of another file _inline_ if you use `r` , no matter what you do.

Comment: gotcha. Might be adequate for the OP though.

Comment: The bash version from the accepted answer works best for me. Nevertheless, a +1 for you because I did not know about `sed`'s `r`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work:

```
$ foo='baz'
$ echo "foobarbaz" | sed "s/foo/${foo}/"
bazbarbaz
```

Taking that one step further, your first line would be something like:

```
$ foo=`cat filename`
```

This assumes you know the filename before you reach the line to be replaced, of course - if you don't, you have to read the line, get the filename, then do the read-and-replace.

Comment: Will this work without checking for escape characters or escaping control characters? Example: the file contains the character `/`.

Comment: I honestly don't know, but given how often I run in to that problem, I'm going to bet it won't.

Comment: Actually, it might:  `foo="baz\bak"` followed by the `echo | sed` works.

Comment: sed will complain if `$foo` contains the delimiter for the `s///` command

Comment: ...not to mention that if the replacement file has more than one line then `s/../../` won't work anyway...