# Replace a line with the full text of a second file

Tags: text-processing, command-line, sed

I know how to replace a line with another line or several other lines with tools like `sed`. But is there an easy way, to replace a line in a file with the whole content of a second file?

So, let's have an example. I have a file  called `file1.txt`:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
```

And I have a second file `file2.txt`:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Now, I want to replace `line 2` with the whole content of `file1.txt`, so in the end, it should look like this

```
line 1
A 1
B 2
C 3
line 3
```

One way I could think about would be something like this:

```
sed -i "s/line 2/$(cat file1.txt)/g" file2.txt.
```

But then I also have to check some special characters like `/` and maybe more. I have to assume, that every possible readable character could be in `file1.txt`.

So, back to my question: Is there an easy way, to replace a line in a file with the whole content of a second file? It doesn't have to be `sed`. It could be also another tool, if it could do the job better...

Comment: Really similar; there may be a better duplicate; https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164551/117549

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -e '/^line 2$/{r file1.txt' -e 'd;}' file2.txt
```

The `sed` script is

```
/^line 2$/{
    r file1.txt
    d
}
```

The newline after the filename `file1.txt` is mandatory, so splitting it up into separate `-e` expressions on the command line makes it arguably more readable than

```
sed '/^line 2$/{r file1.txt
d;}' file2.txt
```

The script looks for a line whose content is `line 2`.  When this is found, the contents of `file1.txt` is immediately outputted and the original line deleted.

Using `sed -i` will make the changes in-line in `file2.txt` (not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

Using vi

Goto the line, then :

```
!!cat filename
```

Current line replaced with contents of file.