# How to replace text between two markers in a file with a section of text from another file?

Tags: bash, text-processing, regular-expression

Say I had a block of text in the `~/.bashrc`:

```
#~/.bashrc
# ...some commands...

# aliases
alias suicide='sudo rm -rf /'
# end aliases

# other commands
```

I wish to replace that block of text with some other text contained between two markers in another file: `stuff-to-place-in-bashrc.txt`

```
# stuff-to-place-in-bashrc.txt
# ...stuff...

# aliases
alias ldir='ls * -d'
alias ithinklifeisworthliving='echo all good'
# end aliases

# ...more stuff...
```

I've tried

```
 sed -ne 's/# aliases\s+\(.*\)\s+# end aliases/\1/' stuff-to-place-in-bashrc.txt
```

But I'm really swinging in the dark here. Could someone help me out?

1. How do I extract the text from the `stuff-to-place-in-bashrc.txt`?
2. How do I replace the other section in `~/.bashrc` with the extracted text from question 1?

### Edit

Thanks for the updates guys, those wondering why i would want something like this:

> allows for cherry-picked updates to script files without overwritting user-made additions. useful for shared and frequently updated standard operating environments (like my last job at [Tyro](http://www.tyro.com) that coded with XP).

go crazy guys.

Comment: Also see [Capture text between curly braces in C preprocessed file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277328/56041). Change "curly braces" with your begin and end tokens (`# aliases` and `# end aliases`), and it may work for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ed is the standard editor, because you can use it to develop ed scripts and let it do its work, as you tested before, interactively. For small files like `.bashrc` or any code text, ed is performant because it reads the whole file in one rush and works with the buffer. For the same reason you should not use ed for big files like log files.

But with an ed script, your job is done in no time:

```
ed ~/.bashrc<<EOF
/^# aliases
+,/^# end aliases/-1d
-r !sed -n '/^# aliases/,/^# end aliases/p' stuff-to-place-in-bashrc.txt|grep -v '^#'
w
q
EOF
```

I use similar scripts to automatically tune configuration files, such als .asoundrc for different environments I take my laptop to.

The best document about ed comes as a simple manual page from the very cool [PLAN9](http://www.plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9/index.html) system. I translated it to a [ed.ps](http://coop.ikrabbe-ask.de/ingo/doc/ed.ps) postscript document.
If you are interested in [PLAN9](http://www.plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9/index.html) you should check [9front](https://code.google.com/p/plan9front/) and http://cat-v.org/ as the original bell labs version is still maintained but has a very simple filesystem.

A final word about editor wars, emacs, vim and the like: [acme rules!](http://acme.cat-v.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It has worked, however I'm not sure what the syntax is. Does it use regex or something more specific to ed? looks like there are vim like commands (`w`,`q`)

Comment: It uses regexes (`/^# aliases`, and `/^# end aliases/`), and the other commands are Vi/Ed. See, for example, http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange for `+, /^# end aliases/`.

Comment: see `info Ed` on your system (hopefully). I don't know why modern linux distributions don't install this cool editor. w and q are write and quit commands. And ed works very similar to sed with regexes. There is a reason why the names sound that similar. d means delete the adressed lines, -r reads into the previous line the results of the `!` command that follows. I shortend the filenames on the edit, as I'm so lazy typing this early morning.

Comment: also how would I extract that text from the stuff-to-place file? It places the whole file inside

Comment: @thenaglecode see my last edit. I had to test that before I posted it.

Comment: great! seems like `ed` is quite powerful, Nice to script vim commands. I'll go away and read some mans, any good tutorials you know of?

Comment: @thenaglecode The one and only really good pages about ed I ever needed was the ed(1) page from plan9: http://man.cat-v.org/plan_9/1/ed I can send you a postscript version if you like. As we are just talking about plan9, see the acme Editor too. If you get used to that, you will never use something else. Of course it's best to use a plan9 system, for example as a virtual machine inside your linux box, but the p9p port for unix is great too. (There are little differences between plan9 ed and gnu ed!)

Answer (score 4):

```
set /^\#aliases/  /^\#end\ aliases/
sed -ne"$1,$2"'s/\\\{0,1\}/&&/gp' <stuff_to_place...rc |
sed -e"$1,$2c\" -f- ./infile >./outfile
```

If you want to edit the file in-place `ed` is a *very* good solution. If you want to edit it in-stream, use `sed`. Avoid `sed -i`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this with `ed` alone, no need for additional tools:

```
ed -s stuff_to_place.txt<<\IN
1,/# aliases/d
/# end aliases/,$d
,d
.r /home/username/.bashrc
/# aliases/x
.t.
.,/# end aliases/-d
,p
q
IN
```

if you're happy with the result, replace `,p` with `w /home/username/.bashrc` to write the changes to `~/.bashrc` (note the full path used with `r` and `w`; you can simply use `.bashrc` if it's in `cwd`).
How this works: we first `d`elete the unneeded lines from `stuff_to_place.txt`. Then we delete the remaining ones (the aliases) with `,d`. The text buffer is now empty while the cut buffer contains the lines we want. We then `r`ead the content of `.bashrc` into the text buffer, put the content of the cut buffer (`x`) to after the `/# aliases/` line, duplicate the last line that was pasted (`.t.`) then delete from the duplicated line up to but not including `/# end aliases/` and finally `p`rint or `w`rite changes and `q`uit.