# Replace one block of text with another block of text when replacement text is in a file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have two files. The fist file is an existing C/C++ source file (`*.cpp`). The second is a text file (`*.txt`) and contains one function. The function is in both files, and it needs to be copied from the second file (`*.txt`) to the first file (`*.cpp`). The function is also rather long (890+ lines), so copy/paste is a bit unwieldy.

I [have a `sed` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277328) to capture the function in the first file (`*.cpp`):

```
ifile=blake2.cpp.old
ofile=blake2.cpp
ffile=blake2-neon.txt
sed -n '/^static void BLAKE2_NEON_Compress64(/,/^}$/p' < $ifile > $ofile
```

What I don't know is how to tell `sed` to replace the text it has captured. I've tried to work through the [GNU sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-Programs.html#sed-Programs), but I'm not having much luck. One of the first things to do is drop the `/p`.

How do I tell `sed` to replace the block of text it finds with the text from another file?

---

I found a similar question at [How to replace text between two markers in a file with a section of text from another file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212009) but I don't quite follow whats going on, especially since the question is tagged `sed` but the answers are provided for `ed`.

---

The reason I am trying to script this is: its a port of IA-32 SSE to ARM NEON. I have a script that performs the basic substitutions. After a change, I need to copy the updated function to the source code, scp the code to a device, and then compile it. Lather, rinse, repeat. The manual copy/paste of a 1000 line function at each iteration consumes time better spent on other things.

Comment: Wouldn't an `#include` of the `.txt` file work, if you `scp` the latter as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715373/sed-insert-file-content-after-specific-pattern-match try `sed "/^static void BLAKE2_NEON_Compress64(/,/^}$/ r $ffile" < $ifile > $ofile` and then delete the original line using another sed command

Comment: Thanks again @spasic - switching from Appl'e `sed` to `gsed` fixed the address problem. However, there's something wrong with the suggestion. The source file with the manual copy/paste is 4800 lines long. After the suggestion, its 4276052 lines long.

Comment: what exactly went wrong? see the difference between manual one and one with sed.. maybe the line got matched multiple times?

Comment: also, check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20322/replace-string-with-contents-of-a-file-using-sed

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Match the start of the function, use the read command `r` to read in the text file. Then add a command to delete `d` all lines between the start and end of the function:

```
sed '
/^static void BLAKE2_NEON_Compress64(/r '"$ffile"'
/^static void BLAKE2_NEON_Compress64(/,/^}$/d
' <"$ifile" >"$ofile"
```

---

If the string to replace is on a single line you can try this

```
uuid='c0e4e6b2-81f4-477c-89a4-7656e58719ce'
sed '/^'"$uuid"'/{
 r '"$ffile"'
 d
}' <"$ifile" >"$ofile"
```

Comment: I changed the source file to use a 1-line UUID to make it easier on `sed`.  Could you show the `sed` to read a C++ source file with a UUID in it (normally, this will cause a compile failure), replace the UUID with the text from another file, and write the modified stream to a new C++ source file? It seems like it should be easy (modify your example), but I'm not getting the damn expected results on OS X 10.8. `sed` keeps modifying the C++ source file with a UUID, rather than writing to a new file.

Comment: I'm not sure how `sed` can edit a file unless you use `-i` to edit in place. Perhaps you could edit your original question with your new version. I have edited my answer with what I think you wanted. Note I quoted the filenames this time as otherwise this can cause errors when there are special characters in the filenames.

Comment: Yes, its working fine using the UUID. The script had two variables crossed at the end, and it cause the read and write of files in the quasi-wrong order.