# Find and replace with contents of a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files

I have a file that begins with a few "include" statements, like this:

```
include foo.xyz
include bar.xyz
do c
do d
```

Suppose the file `foo.xyz` contains `do a` and the file `bar.xyz` contains `do b`. How can I write a script that replaces each `include file.xyz` statement with the contexts of `file.xyz`? I want to end up with the following output:

```
do a
do b
do c
do d
```

I tried the solution in "[Replace string with contents of a file using sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20322/replace-string-with-contents-of-a-file-using-sed)" but there the filename is hard-coded. I would like the filename to be dynamically generated, depending on the `include` argument.

Comment: @don_crissti Yes, they're all of the form `include filename.xyz` where `filename.xyz` is assumed to be in the current directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple recursive version with awk. You must create a script in your PATH with

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
$1=="include" && NF>=2 {
   system("'$0' " $2)
   next
}
{print}' "$@"
```

It assumes filenames have no special chars (including spaces) in them.
The awk checks the first word for include, then calls the script to process the file given as 2nd word. Other lines are printed. Note that the `$0` here is *outside* the single quotes of the awk, so is a shell `$0`, ie the script name.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is the idea that by putting the script in PATH, then calling the script via the `system` call, you can resolve `include` statements transitively? If so, that's jolly clever!

Comment: Yes, it is to simplify includes within includes. Of course, if you know you dont have any, a simple `cat` inside the `system()` will do.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -n '^include ' yourfile |
sed  -e 's/:[^ ]* /{ r /'    \
     -e 'G;s/.$/&b&}/'       |
sed -nf - -ep       yourfile
```

that should work. `grep` finds those *include* line numbers, the first `sed` modifies its output to line-number-specific `[num]{r fname\nb\n}` commands, and the second `sed` `p`rints every line which isn't one of those the first scripts for it.

```
{   for   x in  a b
    do    echo "do $x">"file$x.xyz"
          echo "include file$x.xyz"
    done; printf "do %s\n"  c d
}   >yourfile
cat  yourfile
```

---

```
include filea.xyz
include fileb.xyz
do c
do d
```

That just generates your sample and shows *yourfile*.

And this works:

```
grep -n '^include ' yourfile |
sed  -e 's/:[^ ]* /{ r /'    \
     -e 'G;s/.$/&b&}/'       |
sed -nf - -ep       yourfile
```

---

```
do a
do b
do c
do d
```

the `r`ead files can be any size, though, of course, and are not restricted to the single line. The filenames themselves are restricted to a single line, though, but are otherwise more or less unrestricted *(depending on your `sed` - some older `seds` had arbitrary name-length limits, but most used today don't)*.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat  $(grep '^include' file.txt | cut -d" " -f2); grep -v '^include' file.txt
```

First command will `grep` the line starting with `include` in `file.txt`, `cut` the file name part and then `cat` it.

Next command will print all lines except line starting with `include` in `file.txt`

Comment: Thanks Jijin. Does this work if my file has multiple `include` statements?

Comment: Yes. cat command can open multiple files at a time.